# jQuery autocomplete: TypeError: this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have implemented autocomplete on two input fields, a name and an activity. When using Safari or FireFox the box won't show up at the name input field. With this error message in the console:

> TypeError: this.source is not a function. (In 'this.source( { term: value }, this._response() )', 'this.source' is null)

```
= simple_form_for @transaction do |f|
      .span
        = f.input_field :receiver,  as: :autocomplete, source_query: autocomplete_user_name_users_url, field_id: false,  placeholder: 'To', required: true , :autofocus => true
      .span
        = f.input_field :amount, input_html:{ min: '0', max: '999', step: 'any'} , placeholder: 'Amount', required: true
      .span
        = f.input_field :activity, as: :autocomplete, source_query: autocomplete_activity_name_activities_url, field_id: false, placeholder: 'For',required: true
      = f.submit
```

And these are the controllers

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :activity, :name
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :user, :name
end
```

My application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap3-typeahead
//= require bootstrap3-autocomplete-input
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require later
//= require kudosclicker
//= require simple_form_autocomplete
//= require_tree .
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] of your JavaScript as well? As that's where the error seems to be.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I assume you want the application.js?

Comment: It's not what _I want_, but the error isn't related to the code in the question.

Comment: Please add the [mcve] _into the question itself_.